# How to install tkinter in python 3.6 in CentOS release 6.4

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

I have started to play with Python and I went directly to Python 3.6.

I have two Python environments now in my system: Python 2..6.6 and Python 3.6

Python 2.6.6 is under:

## which python

/usr/bin/python

And Python 3.6 is under /opt/python3/bin

My problem is that if I try to import tkinter in Python 3.6 it does not work:

./python3.6
Python 3.6.0 (default, Feb 16 2017, 17:37:36)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import tkinter
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py", line 36, in 
> > >           import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: ****No module named '_tkinter'****

If I do in Python 2.6 it works:

python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 18 2016, 15:13:37)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import Tkinter

PLEASE NOTE, I know that the module is lower case t in Python 3 so instead of import Tkinter, I am typing import tkinter.

My question is: How do I install tkinter in Python 3 in CentOS.

This I what have tried so far:

## yum install python3-tk

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
Setting up Install Process
No package python3-tk available.
Error: Nothing to do

How do I install in CentOS 6 the module tkinter and make Python 3 able to use it?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install tkinter in order to use matplotlib you may try

> import matplotlib
>
> matplotlib.use('Agg')
>
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

It worked for me

Comment: Maha, that is not for installing tkinter, but to import matplotlib. Apart from that Agg is a non interactive backend, meaning that you will only able of saving graphical files, but not displaying them. Thanks for the reply however!

Comment: Yes, I was trying to install tkinter to get matplotlib working in an interactive mode. I didn't manage to do it, That's I used Agg, so at least I can save figures.